# How to select last record from table consider to Year and WorkingPeriod(Month)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:
[image]

I want last [Status] for each [Guid], consider to latest [Year] and [WorkingPeriodTitle].
By the way I know that [WorkingPeriodTitle] should be replace by [WorkingPeriodId].

Comment: How is `WorkingPeriodTitle` relevant? Isn't the last Status for each GUID just the `MAX(ID)` for each GUID as the ID is an identity column?

Comment: *Tiny* images of your data don't help us help you. Please take the time to post it in a consumable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
select
  t.[PaymentAllocationGuid], t.[Status] 
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by [PaymentAllocationGuid] order by [Year] desc, [WorkingPeriodTitle] desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *,
    LAST_VALUE(Status) OVER (PARTITION BY PaymentAllocationGuid ORDER BY Year, 
    WorkingPeriodTitle RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)  
    AS LastStatus
FROM tablexyz
```